# How to concatenate arrays in the way the objects inside are assigned?

Tags: javascript

Okay it was a bit hard to explain what I want. Let me explain in more detail. I have an array of objects. Because the "only" identifier of the arrays elements are their indexes, if we want to change an element we need to know which is the target index. But even if we have the index, I don't want to change the whole object, just assign the new one and "merge" them together.

I have a solution, which is ugly, but at least makes more sense what I want:

```js
const users = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "John",
        hobby: "soccer"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Alice",
        hobby: "squash"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Greg",
        hobby: "guitar"
      }
    ]

    const newUsers = [
      {
        id: 0,
        work: "developer"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        work: "musician"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Roger",
        work: "accountant"
      }
    ]

const concatArray = (newArray, oldArray) => {
  const objectFromArray = array => array.reduce((object, user) => {
    object[user.id] = user;
    return object
  }, {});

  const objectOfOldArray = objectFromArray(oldArray);
  const objectOfNewArray = objectFromArray(newArray);
  
  const allIds = Object.keys({...objectOfOldArray, ...objectOfNewArray})
  
  return allIds.map(id => {
    const oldProps = objectOfOldArray[id] || {};
    const newProps = objectOfNewArray[id] || {};
    return {id, ...oldProps, ...newProps}
  })
}

console.log(concatArray(newUsers, users))
```

It works fine, but there should be a more sufficient solution for this. I mean it's a very small operation, adding some properties to the specified objects, but my solution is too over-complicated to earn this. There should be an easier way to earn this.

Comment: Can new user have an `id` that does not exist in `users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below approach of `Array.forEach`

```js
const users = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "John",
        hobby: "soccer"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Alice",
        hobby: "squash"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Greg",
        hobby: "guitar"
      }
    ]

const newUsers = [
  {
    id: 0,
    work: "developer"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    work: "musician"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Roger",
    work: "accountant"
  }
]

let updatedUsers = {};

[...users, ...newUsers].forEach(d => updatedUsers[d.id] = { ...(updatedUsers[d.id] || {}), ...d })

console.log(Object.values(updatedUsers))
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to expand the newUsers with a completely new user in my snippet. That's where the problem comes from.

Comment: Updated @GergőHorváth

Comment: Maybe it's off-topic, but if I copy the original users in a redux state, and then perform your solutions, the reducer function will remail pure?

Comment: @GergőHorváth it is offtopic, but you'd need to make copy all the objects, not simply the array for the function to be pure, otherwise it would alter the original objects, generating side-effects

Comment: @GergőHorváth Now for pure function I had to change the logic. Pls see updated code.